# Cannot retain the data of old Text-boxes on dynamic addition of others

Tags: javascript, html, dom, asp-classic

Hello Guys i was trying dynamic addition of text box and other controls in Classic ASP through JavaScript but encountered some problem up there.

Though i was able to add new textboxes but was no able to retain their data.

Eg : If i have a button and on click i want to add textboxes to the html page on first click a textbox is added and i enter data in that textbox like STACKOVERFLOW but when again i hit button new textbox2 is also added but textbox1 data goes away.

I changed my ASP code for simple HTML so that it will be easy. Here is the code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <div id ='div1' style="margin-bottom:6px;"></div>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Change link</button>

 <script>
 function myFunction() {
     var p_strContents = '<input name="cust_name_0" id="cust_name_0" value="" type="text" size="0" class="FormTextField" maxlength="6" title="">';
     document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML + p_strContents ;
     //document.getElementById('div1').appendChild(p_strContents);
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I tried using even appendchild but it will throw some error.

If you want to try it directly online use this link and just paste my code will be easy for u guys to check.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_elmnt_innerhtml

I am using JavaScript.

Could you guys help me. Regards...

Comment: dont set innerHTML that recreates everything, use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) or [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead. If you have tried appendChild you have to pass it an element node, not html

Comment: i used appendchild but it throws some error showing that parameter1 is not a node.  How can i pass it as node??.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with this:

```
function myFunction() {     
    var textBx = document.createElement('input');
    textBx.setAttribute('type', 'textbox');
    textBx.setAttribute('class', 'FormTextField');
    textBx.setAttribute('maxlength', '6');
    document.getElementById('div1').appendChild(textBx);
    textBx = null;
 }
```

[Please check working code here](https://jsfiddle.net/mohammed2raja/bpykkkgz/)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked like a charm. Why are u finally setting textBx to null ???

Comment: It does not matter here, but it will create performance issue if you create and append multiple element in a single scope.